# Code inside apex method not running intermittently on button click Aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I'm having a parent and child Aura component. There is a button on the parent component that invokes a js action and it further calls a aura enabled apex method.

The issue is it is calling the apex method every time, but frequently it is not executing the code inside the method.
When I examine the debug logs, it just shows only the below chunk and nothing else apart from this. But, some time, the log is very detailed and it executes the code inside the apex method.

I'm really confused what is going on.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
57.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
14:20:39.0 (441850)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0055G00000ABCD|demouser@demodomain.com.demouser|(GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)|GMT-05:00
14:20:39.0 (482970)|EXECUTION_STARTED
14:20:39.0 (489005)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|apex://MyEMPController/ACTION$fetchEmployees
14:20:39.0 (2143359)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|apex://MyEMPController/ACTION$fetchEmployees
14:20:39.0 (2161017)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Assuming you don't have bad parameters (check your browser's F12 Developer Console for errors), then it's just a matter of your Debug Log Levels being set incorrectly. This is the kind of log I'd expect the levels were set to the absolute minimum, or there was a bad parameter. Without seeing your code, though, it's hard to provide specifically useful information.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Please let me check my code quickly.